# Artifactory replication after connection reset

Tags: replication, artifactory

Does artifactory cache partial replicated files on remote repositories and then resume download after the connection is established again? Or does is start the download replication all over after a connection reset?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not 100% clear. Are you asking if the replication from remote Artifactory instance will continue from where it stopped in case of connection reset or do you mean that you started to resolve an artifact from a remote repository and the connection was stopped?

Replication will basically start a file list from the remote Artifactory instance and will replicate any missing item, meaning that you have 10 files on a remote instance and the connection interrupted after 5 files have already been replicated, Artifactory replication will only replicate the remaining 5 files and not the whole 10.

In case it's the second case than in case a remote download was interrupted before the file was downloaded completely, than you will need to download the entire file again.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I mean the 2nd case. I apologize for the unclear question. I'm basically executing a performance test with 1GB files and introduce intermittent connection resets. The file never downloads because it appears as if the download start all over again every connection reset. I was wondering if there was a setting a cache partial remote downloads in case of connection resets.

Comment: So, unfortunately, the answer is no. Artifactory is not performing like a download manager with "resume download"